# ZTE Open userAgent String

Tags: firefox-os

could someone plz provide me the User-Agent-String (navigator.userAgent) of the ZTE Open device? I need it to disable memory-hungry features in my app on devices with 256 MB of RAM. There's no way to get information about available RAM at the moment and I can't do those features with less memory consumption. (on 512 MB RAM they will work)

By now I have those User-Agent-Strings:

**ALCATEL One Touch Fire**

`Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; ALCATELOneTouch4012X; rv:18.1) Gecko/18.1 Firefox/18.1`

**GeeksPhone Keon**

`Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; rv:18.1) Gecko/18.1 Firefox/18.1`

greetings, André

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; ZTEOPEN; rv:18.1) Gecko/18.1 Firefox/18.1
```

[Source](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Compatibility/UADetectionLibraries).

Also, if you want to know the LG Fireweb UA string, it is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; LG-D300; rv:18.1) Gecko/18.1 Firefox/18.1
```

**Long answer**

The Keon UA string is actually the Mozilla's recommended UA string for all Firefox OS smartphones. See the [gecko user agent string reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference), which means that you can be serving the simplified version of your website for devices with lots of RAM in the future, devices that would use the recommended string and that are not Geeksphone Keon, a Nexus 4 running Firefox OS for example.

And that is the trouble of using user agent sniffing. That practice should be avoided whenever possible because of it's fragility as you may already know… relying on UA sniffing instead of feature detection is not a good practice.

There are some ways to test the performance of your page without trying to guess which device/platform/version your visitor uses, RequestAnimationFrame can be an alternative way to probe the actual responsiveness of your app for example, but I don't know if that would be enough for your usecase.

Comment: Hi Fabricio and thanks for you long answer! :) I know user agent sniffing isn't good practice. I'm building a image editor app for FFOS. It uses some heavy webgl shaders, on devices with low memory (256 MB) they will fail rendering the final image with full resolution (in one piece). I know I could implement some pattern/cascaded rendering that fill fix this issue. But by now I will just get it in the app store. So on low-memory devices I want to limit the export resolution to 1600px.

Comment: @AndréFiedler What would be the information you need from the device to know if it can support your app outside of User Agent sniffing guessing.

Comment: The amount of free RAM

Answer (score 2):

I got

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; rv:18.0) Gecko/18.0 Firefox/18.0
```

with my ZTE Open running 1.0.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a list of Firefox OS devices for WhichBrowser - a user agent sniffing library. It currently contains the following device identifiers for Firefox OS:

```
DeviceModels::$FIREFOXOS_MODELS = array(
    'ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 4012A'                   => array( 'Alcatel', 'One Touch Fire' ),
    'ALCATELOneTouch4012A'                      => array( 'Alcatel', 'One Touch Fire' ),
    'ALCATELOneTouch4012X'                      => array( 'Alcatel', 'One Touch Fire' ),
    'ALCATELOneTouch4019X'                      => array( 'Alcatel', 'One Touch Fire C' ),
    'LG-D300'                                   => array( 'LG', 'Fireweb' ),
    'ZTEOPEN'                                   => array( 'ZTE', 'Open' ),
    'OpenC'                                     => array( 'ZTE', 'Open C' ),
);
```

An up-to-date version can be found here:
https://github.com/NielsLeenheer/WhichBrowser/blob/master/data/models-firefoxos.php

Answer (score 0):

I got a [hint](http://forum.geeksphone.com/index.php?topic=5785.0) that I can read `/proc/meminfo` with the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to get detailed memory info on all devices. Have to check this later. :)

**Edit:**

Can't get it working. I tried this **invalid** one:

```
var file = new File('/proc/meminfo');
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.result);
};
reader.readAsText(file);
```

Then I tried this one:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', '/proc/meminfo', true);
req.onreadystatechange = function (evt) {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
      alert(req.responseText);
  }
};
req.send(null);
```

And I tried it with `"systemXHR": {}` permission:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest({
    mozSystem: true
});
req.open('GET', '/proc/meminfo', true);
req.onreadystatechange = function (evt) {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
      alert(req.responseText);
  }
};
req.send(null);
```

nothing did work.