# Firefox OS get device information

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, firefox-os

I'm trying to get general device information (e.g. Name, Brand etc..) on Firefox OS but i'm struggling with the "Settings API"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Platform/Settings_list and this set of API is available only for certified apps.

Is this the only way? How can I access to Device Name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `navigator.userAgent` [1] to see name and brand of some devices without any permission.

For Alcatel One Touch Fire, for example, you will get: `Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 4012A; rv:18.1) Gecko/18.1 Firefox/18.1`

Keon and Peak, unfortunately, will only return a generic UA. You can see more UA strings at [2].

[1] http://w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_nav_all
[2] [ZTE Open userAgent String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103893/zte-open-useragent-string)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! In my opinion,there should be a way by API to achieve that!

Comment: Hi Fran, you can submit your suggestion at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/. Look before if it's not already there.

Comment: Hi Frederic, just suggested on bugzilla.mozilla.org. 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=946203